# Didn't find class "android.view.layout"

Tags: java, android

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mzz.work.login_signup-MmKrHS_eKGNcUeNOjZ3Bqg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:723)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:740)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:808)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:844)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2020-01-21 21:39:19.510 18902-18902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)



at mzz.work.login_signup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
```

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import mzz.work.login_signup.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import mzz.work.login_signup.login.LoginFragment;
import mzz.work.login_signup.login.SignUpFragment;

import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;
import static mzz.work.login_signup.FlexibleFrameLayout.ORDER_LOGIN_STATE;
import static mzz.work.login_signup.FlexibleFrameLayout.ORDER_SIGN_UP_STATE;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private boolean isLogin = true;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginFragment topLoginFragment = new LoginFragment();
        SignUpFragment topSignUpFragment = new SignUpFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.login_fragment, topLoginFragment)
                .replace(R.id.sign_up_fragment, topSignUpFragment)
                .commit();

        binding.loginFragment.setRotation(-90);

        binding.button.setOnSignUpListener(topSignUpFragment);
        binding.button.setOnLoginListener(topLoginFragment);
        binding.button.setOnButtonSwitched(new OnButtonSwitchedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonSwitched(boolean isLogin) {
                binding.getRoot()
                        .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
                                ctx,
                                isLogin ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.secondPage));
            }
        });

        binding.loginFragment.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        binding.loginFragment.setPivotX(binding.loginFragment.getWidth() / 2);
        binding.loginFragment.setPivotY(binding.loginFragment.getHeight());
        binding.signUpFragment.setPivotX(binding.signUpFragment.getWidth() / 2);
        binding.signUpFragment.setPivotY(binding.signUpFragment.getHeight());
    }

    public void switchFragment(View v) {
        if (isLogin) {
            binding.loginFragment.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            binding.loginFragment.animate().rotation(0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    binding.signUpFragment.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    binding.signUpFragment.setRotation(90);
                    binding.wrapper.setDrawOrder(ORDER_LOGIN_STATE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            binding.signUpFragment.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            binding.signUpFragment.animate().rotation(0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    binding.loginFragment.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                    binding.loginFragment.setRotation(-90);
                    binding.wrapper.setDrawOrder(ORDER_SIGN_UP_STATE);
                }
            });
        }

        isLogin = !isLogin;
        binding.button.startAnimation();
    }

}
```

Comment: it is better if you migrate to androidx

Comment: Could be a problem with your activity_main layout.

Answer (score 9):

Data binding might not be initialized in your app level build.gradle file. Please add **dataBinding.enabled true** in that file.

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29

        dataBinding.enabled true
        .........
```